# Do the Solidity v0.8 overflow checks apply to assembly operations too?

Tags: assembly, overflow, math, solidity-0.8.x

[Since Solidity v0.8](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/080-breaking-changes.html), the compiler has checks for {over,under}flow by default for all arithmetic operations.

Do these checks apply to assembly ([yul](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/yul.html)) arithmetic operations too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they apply only to non-assembly code. Check for yourself on [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

contract Mul {
    function mul_normal(uint8 x, uint8 y) external pure returns (uint8 result) {
        result = x * y;    
    }
    
    function mul_assembly(uint8 x, uint8 y) external pure returns (uint8 result) {
        assembly {
            result := mul(x, y)
        }
    }
}
```

Passing 255 and 2 as `x` and `y`, respectively, reverts when calling `mul_normal` but yields 254 when calling `mul_assembly`:

[image: Remix Screenshot]